# Jedis connection refused

Tags: java, redis, connection, jedis, nosql

I'm trying to connect to my virtual machine Redis

```
package nosql;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;

public class NoSQL {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //I try port:               ("127.0.0.1",6379)
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis("127.0.0.1",60448);
    if(jedis.isConnected())
    System.out.println("connected");
    jedis.ping();

    jedis.set("key1", "value1");
    System.out.println(jedis.get("key1"));

}

}
```

My Redis configuration:

[image: Redis configuration]

I have already put the virtual machine in bridge mode (I do not know if there has).

I am researching the hours and not getting answers.

Does anyone know what the error?

Comment: Looks like a config issue between your VM and the client/host. Figure out the public IP address of your VM and connect to the <IP>:6379 (and not localhost:60448)

Answer (score 0):

just run the server "redis-server" in the main redis folder
and run the above program
that would do the job.